# Error express metodo next() en funcion app.all

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, backend, server

estoy aprendiendo expressJs y tengo un error cuando quiero utilizar el método de ruteo básico app.all.

```
app.all('/usuario', req, res, next) =>{
  console.log('Uso este para todos los usuarios dentro de mi app');
  next();  //Aquí tengo el error 
});
```

El error es al utilizar la funcion next() que me da express, en la consola de node me dice que no está definida, sin embargo entiendo que al llamar al modulo 'express' dentro de una constante debería funcionar sin problemas, también checando la documentación veo que sigue utilizando así actualmente, no se donde puede estar mi error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que tienes un error en la forma en que estas construyendo el enrutamiento. La sintaxis es el alias de tu método *('/usuarios')*, y luego el `callback`. Modifícalo así y nos comentas si te sirve

```
app.all('/usuarios', (req, res, next) => {...})
```

**[Acá](https://expressjs.com/es/guide/routing.html)** te dejo la documentación de enrutamiento para Express

Comment: Exactamente compañero Paulo, tienes toda la razón, muchas gracias por responder!